# Angular.js : Why ng-model won't throw "Uncaught TypeError" exception when referring to a property which doesn't exist?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
var a = {b:null};
a.b.c.d;
```

The code above results in an error, saying that `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'c' of null`.

However, I noticed that `ng-model` doesn't throw any exception when I do something like...

```
<input ng-model="a.b.c.d"/>
//Assuming that I use the same variable above
```

This `ng-model` gets false, but I think this should results in an error, instead of returning a boolean value.

Why does this happen? I'm searching Stackoverflow, but can't find any reason why.

Any advice will be appreciated.

Comment: From `ng-model` docs: `If the property in the ng-model attribute does not exist, AngularJS will create one for you.` - see https://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_model.asp

Comment: @OvidiuDolha Why w3schools when there's [official docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel#overview)? (See **Note:** under list of `ng-Model`'s responsibilities)

Comment: @barbsan you are right

Comment: ng-model will create that  variable for you. That's why not throwing any error